# CMD script that goes to a folder

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to make a CMD script that will do `CD Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts` and enter it, then I want to be able to type a command. Is there a way I can make a script to start in the `Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts` directory on my computer?

Comment: I think what you really want is to create a symlink that will be like a shortcut to that folder you want.  What OS are you on, mac, win or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Put this into a blank text file called MyScript.CMD

Double click it.

```
@echo off
CMD /K CD /D "%userprofile%\Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts"
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a symbolic link on Windows, open Command Prompt ([as an Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)). Let's say your username is Jason. And the symlink we will name 'code'.

```
cd \Users\Jason
mklink /D code Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts
cd code
dir
```

All your files in pyscripts will be listed. You basically have created a shortcut to your pyscripts.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the folder name

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd simply create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` and set Properties/shortcut/Startin to Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts.

If you really want to jump to pyscripts from within an existing `cmd` instance, then create a textfile named 'pyscripts.bat' containing

```dos
@echo off
CD "%userprofile%\Desktop\Crunchyroll\pyscripts"
```

and store it somewhere in your **PATH**.

Then executing `pyscripts` from within a `cmd` instance will jump to the indicated directory and

```dos
....
PUSHD
call pyscripts
{do some python}
POPD
...
```

should allow you to execute python from that directory within a batch file.